# Change form of eigenvectors from eig function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am attempting to multiply the eigenvectors that I am getting from the eig function by my original matrix, but it is giving me a "matrices are not aligned" error. Here is the code I want to run:

```
import numpy.matlib 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.linalg import eig
#M is a previously defined NxN matrix

evals, evecs = eig(Mnp, left=False,right=True)

def chop(expr, tol=0.0000000009):
  expr.real[abs(expr.real) < tol] = 0.0
  expr.imag[abs(expr.imag) < tol] = 0.0
  return expr
evecs = chop(evecs)

lamda=evals[1]
mM=np.matrix(M)
mm=np.matrix(mM-lamda*np.identity(N))

for x in np.where(evals==lamda)[0]:
  print(mm*np.matrix(evecs[:,x]))
```

What is wrong with this? How do I force the eigenvectors to output in the right form? Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to perform a matrix multiplication in `mm*np.matrix(evecs[:,x])`? If yes, then use `np.dot(mm, evecs[:,x])`.

Comment: I tried the np.dot and it didn't make the error go away (and yes I am trying to do matrix multiplication)

Comment: I don't have any error when replacing with dot and removing np.matrix. What error do you get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy.matlib 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.linalg import eig

N = 13
Mnp = np.random.random((n,n))

evals, evecs = eig(Mnp, left=False,right=True)

def chop(expr, tol=0.0000000009):
    expr.real[abs(expr.real) < tol] = 0.0
    expr.imag[abs(expr.imag) < tol] = 0.0
    return expr
evecs = chop(evecs)

lamda=evals[1]
mM=np.matrix(M)
mm=np.matrix(mM-lamda*np.identity(N))

for x in np.where(evals==lamda)[0]:
    print(np.matmul(mm,evecs[:,x]))
```

This does what you want I reckon. You just need to use np.matmul(A,b) where A.shape[1] == b.shape[0] returns True. You could also use np.dot(A,b).